# defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); if i will not use then how can access directly

Tags: php, codeigniter

As mentioned no direct script access allowed but if i will not use this line then how can i can get direct access??

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

what will be the total criteria??

Comment: No direct script access allowed, If your BASEPATH is not defined.

Comment: OK - take a couple of steps back and tell us exactly what the problem is... do you mean *How would Jeff the H4Xx0R access a file when the BASEPATH isn't defined?* ... this question isn't very clear.

Comment: it's perfectly clear to me, the environment variable isn't set so the script exits.

Comment: @delboy1978uk - that's not how the following line reads to me though: *"if i will not use this line then how can i can get direct access?"* - sounds like he's asking how could someone get direct access when that `defined('BASEPATH') ...` line isn't in the code.

Comment: if he takes that line out, the code that comes after will work. i don't see what's hard at all about this.

Comment: of course if any code refers to BASEPATH then it will still break. He just needs to define the site root as his basepath

Comment: @delboy1978uk - it's not that it's hard, it's a matter of **what** is the **actual** question?

Comment: i believe his question is how to get the code running without it `exit()`ing

Comment: @delboy1978uk ... whereas I suspect it might be security oriented, relating to file access (and whether files are under the docroot or not) ... so, since we're both seeing a different question here, I'd suggest it's *unclear what the OP is asking*.

Comment: He hasn't set his codeigniter project up correctly, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php

`define()` sets a constant Environment variable, and `defined()` checks it is set. If you are using apache you can set this in the VHost configuration (or in the `.htaccess`) using SetEnv

`SetEnv BASEPATH /path/to/webroot`

This sounds like a codeigniter project to me. Everything *should* be going through `public/index.php`, if you look there you should see BASEPATH being defined somewhere.

So, it sounds possibly like it could be that your apache isn't marshalling requests through your front controller. Again check your vhost configuration, or `public/.htaccess`